# Problems INSERTing record if similar doesn't already exist

Tags: python, mysql, select

I'm trying to check whether a record already exists in the database (by similar title), and insert it if not. I've tried it two ways and neither quite works.

More elegant way (?) using IF NOT EXISTS

```
if mode=="update":
    #check if book is already present in the system
    cursor.execute('IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM book WHERE TITLE LIKE "%s") INSERT INTO book (title,author,isbn) VALUES ("%s","%s","%s") END IF;' % (title,title,author,isbn))
    cursor.execute('SELECT bookID FROM book WHERE TITLE LIKE "%s";' % (title))
    bookID = cursor.fetchall()
    print('found the bookid %s' % (bookID))
    #cursor.execute('INSERT INTO choice (uid,catID,priority,bookID) VALUES ("%d","%s","%s","%s");' % ('1',cat,priority,bookID)) #commented out because above doesn't work
```

With this, I get an error on the IF NOT EXISTS query saying that "author" isn't defined (although it is).

Less elegant way using count of matching records

```
if mode=="update":
    #check if book is already present in the system
    cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book WHERE title LIKE "%s";' % (title))
    anyresults = cursor.fetchall()
    print('anyresults looks like %s' % (anyresults))
    if anyresults[0] == 0: # if we didn't find a bookID
        print("I'm in the loop for adding a book")
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO book (title,author,isbn) VALUES ("%s","%s","%s");' % (title,author,isbn))
    cursor.execute('SELECT bookID FROM book WHERE TITLE LIKE "%s";' % (title))
    bookID = cursor.fetchall()
    print('found the bookid %s' % (bookID))
    #cursor.execute('INSERT INTO choice (uid,catID,priority,bookID) VALUES ("%d","%s","%s","%s");' % ('1',cat,priority,bookID)) #commented out because above doesn't work
```

In this version, anyresults is a tuple that looks like (0L,) but I can't find a way of matching it that gets me into that "loop for adding a book." if anyresults[0] == 0, 0L, '0', '0L' -- none of these seem to get me into the loop.

I think I may not be using IF NOT EXISTS correctly--examples I've found are for separate procedures, which aren't really in the scope of this small project.

ADDITION:
I think unutbu's code will work great, but I'll still getting this dumb NameError saying author is undefined which prevents the INSERT from being tried, even when I am definitely passing it in.

```
if form.has_key("title"): 
    title = form['title'].value
    mode = "update"
if form.has_key("author"): 
    author = form['author'].value
    mode = "update"
    print("I'm in here")
if form.has_key("isbn"):
    isbn = form['isbn'].value
    mode = "update"
```

It never prints that "I'm in here" test statement. What would stop it getting in there? It seems so obvious--I keep checking my indentation, and I'm testing it on the command line and definitely specifying all three parameters.

Comment: SQL injection, go go go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up a UNIQUE index on `book`, then inserting unique rows is easy.

For example,

```
mysql> ALTER IGNORE TABLE book ADD UNIQUE INDEX book_index (title,author);
```

WARNING: if there are rows with non-unique (title,author) pairs, all but one such row will be dropped.

If you want just the `author` field to be unique, then just change `(title,author)` to `(author)`.

Depending on how big the table, this may take a while...

Now, to insert a unique record,

```
sql='INSERT IGNORE INTO book (title,author,isbn) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
cursor.execute(sql,[title,author,isbn])
```

If `(title,author)` are unique, the triplet `(title,author,isbn)` is inserted into the `book` table.

If `(title,author)` are not unique, then the `INSERT` command is ignored.

Note, the second argument to `cursor.execute`. Passing arguments this way helps prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you--this is a smarter way to do it because I do want to be able to have multiple books with the same title as long as they're by different authors. I do still have one bug, where it says that "author" is undefined even when the form does have author filled out. I have two "if" in a row and it never makes it inside the second one. I added the snipped above.

Comment: @umbraphile: Somehow, `form.has_key("author")` must be False. Is `form` a dict? Can you print `form` or `form.keys()` to see what keys it has? What do you want to happen if `form` has no `author` key?

Comment: Yep, that was it. It took me a while to figure out why the other form values were vanishing but it works now. Thanks again.

Comment: @umbraphile: great! glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question since it's for Postgresql rather than MySQL, but I figured I'd drop it in for people searching their way here.

In Postgres, you can batch insert items if they don't exist:

```
CREATE TABLE book (title TEXT, author TEXT, isbn TEXT);

# Create a row of test data:
INSERT INTO book (title,author,isbn) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c');

# Do the real batch insert:
INSERT INTO book
SELECT add.* FROM (VALUES
 ('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('d', 'e', 'f'),
 ('g', 'h', 'i'),
) AS add (title, author, isbn)
LEFT JOIN book ON (book.title = add.title)
WHERE book.title IS NULL;
```

This is pretty simple.  It selects the new rows as if they're a table, then left joins them against the existing data.  The rows that don't already exist will join against a NULL row; we then filter out the ones that already exist (where book.title isn't NULL).  This is extremely fast: it takes only a single database transaction to do a large batch of inserts, and lets the database backend do a bulk join, which it's very good at.

By the way, you really need to stop formatting your SQL queries directly (unless you really have to and really know what you're doing, which you don't here).  Use query substitution, eg. `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE title=? and isbn=?", (title, isbn))`.